# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout doesn't scroll to incomplete group

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I have simple implementation with `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. There are two sections, every has single row with horizontal scroll and every item at section has 1/4 width of whole container (now it's full screen).

I would like to have paging scroll, but when data source provides **4n+1** elements at the section I can't scroll to access last item.

How to fix it with pure animation for last item like with simple `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`?

```
func createCollectionViewLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, environment -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1 / 4), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.4))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 4)

        let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(44))
        let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging
        section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [header]

        return section
    }
}
```

[Video with bug example](https://vimeo.com/524786521)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After complex research: seems like layout bug, one possible solution is to change programmatically the `orthogonalScrollingBehavior` depending on the number of items